# How to restore an accidentally deleted GPO. Please advise

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, gpo

I have deleted one GPO from DC (Windows server 2012 R2). How do i restore it back. Domain Function level is 2008 R2. Is there any option.? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Did I answer your question? Can you please accept it if I did?

Answer (score 0):

**To restore a deleted GPO:**

1. In the Group Policy Management Console tree, click Change Control in
   the forest and domain in which you want to manage GPOs.
2. On the Contents tab, click the Recycle Bin tab to display the deleted GPOs.
3. Right-click the GPO to restore, and then click Restore.
4. Type a comment to be displayed in the history of the GPO, and then click OK.
5. When the Progress window indicates that overall progress is
   complete, click Close. The GPO is removed from the Recycle Bin tab
   and is displayed on the Controlled tab.

Source:  [Restore a Deleted GPO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/agpm/restore-a-deleted-gpo)